# Get PHP to display warnings and errors only

Tags: php

How do I set PHP to display warnings and errors and not to show notices?

Comment: But you should also take care of the notices. They are there for a reason. Just disable them does not make the potential problem go away.

Comment: @FelixKling: It sufficies to be *notified* once, since the issues are normally speculative. There is a difference between ignoring them and just disabling their display. (Btw, custom error handlers [logs] still can see them, whereas syntactic `isset` salt will forfeit them completely.)

Comment: @mario: Disabling error_reporting E_NOTICE level not only disables their display, but the logging as well. You can enable the PHP `ignore_repeated_errors` INI directive to be notified only once if you want to. No need to completely disable E_NOTICE.

Comment: @netcoder: Depends. Using a `set_error_handler` will get you all notices even for `error_reporting(0)`, which I use for logging to unclog the httpd.log. Nice tip on the `ignore_repeated_errors`, seems rather useful for development stage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this into your `php.ini` file:

```
error_reporting = E_ERROR | E_WARNING
display_errors  = 1
```

**EDIT**: As @Felix said, you should probably have those notices show as well. They are there for a reason.

Comment: do you know how to set this from php.ini file?

Comment: @Adamski Find `display_errors` and set it to `1`. `error_reporting()` is a runtime setting I'm pretty sure.

Comment: How do you set this in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` using `php_value`?